# R - Reading ISO8601 format

Tags: r, datetime, iso8601

Is there a better way to parse ISO8601 date representations than what I did, below?

The input datetime was formatted to an ISO8601 Standard representation (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm-hh:mm), i.e. year-month-dayTlocaltime-UTCoffset. The UTC offset would be -ve for New York, as shown, and +ve for Warsaw, for example. I read this into R using two lines of code as follows:

First, I removed the ":" from the UTC offset (R is expecting the format nnnn for the UTC offset):

```
    dataset$nocolon<- paste(substr(dataset$timestampISO8601,1,22),substr(dataset$timestampISO8601,24,25),sep="")
```

Then, I parsed the timestamps to get UTC time:

```
    dataset$datetimeUTC <- strptime(dataset$nocolon, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tz="UTC")
```

Comment: Better in what way? What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Add some example dates from your inputs, few people are going to be bothered to construct test cases otherwise.

Comment: This question should be closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592178/r-utc-to-local-time-given-olson-timezones

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pandas default output format for local time, so it should be encountered frequently. I converted your solution into one-liner:

```
v = "2009-01-27 20:02:22+01:00"
as.POSIXct(gsub(":","",v),  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S%z")
```